# Loading two of the same jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm using this slider [Slider](http://callmenick.com/post/responsive-content-slider)

My issue is I have 2 of them on my page. Separate they work fine. Together one breaks the other.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#cslide-slides").cslide();
        $("#cslide-slider").cslide();
    });
```

So if I use one by it's self. It will run fine no errors. When I put them together the one on the bottom will load correctly and the one on top will break. So if I swap them the top will break bottom will work. I have no idea what the issue could be.

So by "break" I mean that the lining and css is all messed up. The data shows but the items within the slider are all over the place within the panel.

Anyone explain to me what could be happening?

Comment: Looks like a poorly written plugin that doesn't isolate instances. Find a different one unless you want to refactor the plugin itself

Comment: @charlietfl maybe so, but the author's page specifically says `And there you have it. A neat jQuery function that allows you to create as many responsive content sliders as you want, as long as they have unique id’s and follow a certain markup.`  I would check the markup!

Comment: @James Well this specific  line  `$(".cslide-slide").css({   width : slideWidth});`  affects all instances

Comment: I was looking at that and figured that's what it was. When The last one is loaded then the slidewidth is changed.

Comment: @charlietfl that indeed looks like a bug!